# copy text from several textboxes to one specific textbox with linebreaks for each new text box

Tags: c#

Forgive the long title!

I am just starting out learning C# as a hobby really to make simple programs in my spare time. I decided to make (what i thought would be a simple little program to log notes) I have searched for sample code on this to try and figure out how to implement it but cannot find exactly what i am looking for.

Here is what i need it to do.

I have 8 textboxes setup and 4 checkboxes setup. When a user types into textbox1 i need it to be typed into textbox 8 + Newline. Type in textbox2 it should go in textbox 8 as well with another Newline and so on and so on through textbox 7. If the user selects the checkboxes it will put a predetermined text into textbox8 with a space. All out put from every textbox/checkbox should go into textbox8.

I have tried 
`notes_view_text.Text = cust_name_text.Text;`
in each of my textboxes(with the names changed obviously) and also tried 
  `Environment.NewLine`
and i can either get one textbox to type and then when i go to the next it clears my textbox 8 or it will go to another line on every keystroke.

I am sure i am missing something very simple that requires a very basic understanding of the language and for that i apologize. Also if this is more difficult then i thought please let me know and i will attempt in a different language or forget about it. I just wanted to create this to make logging notes and copying them to clipboard(know how to do that part heh) in my job easier.

Comment: @alex, there is a rollback link you can use :-). Click on the link that shows you last editing it to see.

Comment: @Ben - it's not visible to me because I don't have 2k reputation yet - otherwise, I would have used it :)

Answer (score 4):

To add text to an existing string, use += instead of =, like

```
notes_view_text.Text += cust_name_text.Text + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for responding. I did try this before but i tried it again just for sake of me probably missing something. With this code whenever i type into a textbox it logs every keystroke in to the notes_view_text.Text for example.
If i type into cust_name_text.Text "Hello" in notes_view_text i get the following 
H
He
Hel
Hell
Hello

Comment: The combine() function suggested below seems like the best option. You could call it every time any text box changes (add an event handler for each text box's TextChanged event [properties window, Events category] and call combine() which will rebuild the whole string for every key press).

Your event handler must have an object and EventArgs as parameters, like:
private void textBoxYMin_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

Answer (score 2):

Please let me know if this helps:

```
void combine()
{
    box8.Text = box1.Text;
    box8.Text += Environment.NewLine;
    box8.Text += box2.Text
    box8.Text += Environment.NewLine;
    box8.Text += box3.Text
    box8.Text += Environment.NewLine;
    box8.Text += box4.Text
    box8.Text += Environment.NewLine;
    box8.Text += box5.Text
    box8.Text += Environment.NewLine;
    box8.Text += box6.Text
    box8.Text += Environment.NewLine;
    box8.Text += box7.Text
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what i was trying to do from the start and is what made sense to me as well only problem i am getting is when i enter this code i get no error but i am also getting no output to textbox8. I am guessing i am missing something as to where i need the code. Thanks

Comment: Maybe i need to add in an event handler to where i press enter it will go to the next textbox create a new line in the output textbox and then be ready to do the same again with the current box? Not sure i know how to do all that though lol